# How to translate this IL Code to Reflection.Emit in C#?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

This is the IL code I'm trying to translate to C# without succes:

```
    .assembly _
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilationRelaxationsAttribute::.ctor(int32) = (
        01 00 08 00 00 00 00 00
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 01 00 54 02 16 57 72 61 70 4e 6f 6e 45 78
        63 65 70 74 69 6f 6e 54 68 72 6f 77 73 01
    )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute::.ctor(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes) = (
        01 00 02 00 00 00 00 00
    )
    .hash algorithm 0x00008004 // SHA1
    .ver 0:0:0:0
}

.class private auto ansi '<Module>'
{
} // end of class <Module>

.class public auto ansi MYCLASS
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
{
    // Fields
    .field private object _myTextBlock
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
        01 00 00 00
    )

    // Methods
    .method public specialname rtspecialname 
        instance void .ctor () cil managed 
    {
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
        // Code size 23 (0x17)
        .maxstack 8

        // sequence point: hidden
        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: call instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_0006: ldarg.0
        IL_0007: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Object::.ctor()
        IL_000c: call object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
        IL_0011: call instance void MYCLASS::set_myTextBlock(object)
        IL_0016: ret
    } // end of method MYCLASS::.ctor

    .method public specialname 
        instance object get_myTextBlock () cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2068
        // Code size 7 (0x7)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldfld object MYCLASS::_myTextBlock
        IL_0006: ret
    } // end of method MYCLASS::get_myTextBlock

    .method public specialname 
        instance void set_myTextBlock (
            object AutoPropertyValue
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute::.ctor() = (
            01 00 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x2070
        // Code size 13 (0xd)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.0
        IL_0001: ldarg.1
        IL_0002: call object [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::GetObjectValue(object)
        IL_0007: stfld object MYCLASS::_myTextBlock
        IL_000c: ret
    } // end of method MYCLASS::set_myTextBlock

    // Properties
    .property instance object myTextBlock()
    {
        .get instance object MYCLASS::get_myTextBlock()
        .set instance void MYCLASS::set_myTextBlock(object)
    }

    } // end of class MYCLASS
```

This is what I'm translating from:

```
public class MYCLASS : object
{
    public object myTextBlock { get; set; } = new object();
}
```

This is what I have so far that is working but is not inheriting the class or initialising the properties:

```
    public Type CreateClass(string className, Dictionary<string, Type> properties)
{
    AssemblyName myAsmName = new AssemblyName("RoadAssembly");
    AssemblyBuilder myAssembly = myAssembly.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);


    ModuleBuilder myModule = myAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("RoadAssembly");

    TypeBuilder myType = myModule.DefineType(className, TypeAttributes.Public);

    myType.DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

    foreach (var o in properties)
    {
        PropertyBuilder prop = myType.DefineProperty(o.Key, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, o.Value, null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */);

        FieldBuilder field = myType.DefineField("_" + o.Key, o.Value, FieldAttributes.Private);


        MethodBuilder getter = myType.DefineMethod("get_" + o.Key, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, o.Value, Type.EmptyTypes);
        ILGenerator getterIL = getter.GetILGenerator();
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field);
        getterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        MethodBuilder setter = myType.DefineMethod("set_" + o.Key, MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null/* TODO Change to default(_) if this is not a reference type */, new Type[] { o.Value });
        ILGenerator setterIL = setter.GetILGenerator();
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
        setterIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);




        prop.SetGetMethod(getter);
        prop.SetSetMethod(setter);
    }

    return myType.CreateType();
}
```

I have tried making a constructor for the type to translate the "New Object" part with no success, this is my attempted constructor:

```
{
    ConstructorBuilder cBuilder = myType.DefineConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName, CallingConventions.Standard, new Type[] { o.Value });
    ConstructorInfo conObj = typeof(object).GetConstructor(new Type[0] { });
    ILGenerator cil = cBuilder.GetILGenerator();

    cil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    cil.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, conObj);
    cil.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field);
    cil.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    cil.Emit(OpCodes.Call, conObj);
    cil.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}
```

I do not understand how the OpCodes work or where I have to place this constructor in my function so I can properly initialise the objects of this class when I create an object of this class.

Comment: The "working" code you have shown doesn't seem compile, and it's not clear what you mean when you say it "is not inheriting the class". Show what you're trying to do in context, as well as any errors, and the desired behavior.

Comment: The "working" code can only create a class with whatever properties are in the dictionary, and it compiles in .NET, so I have no idea why it wouldn't work for you. I have already shown what I want to replicate from IL in C#, I have also shown what I have succeeded in replicating from IL to C#, I do not know what else to show.

Comment: The code does not compile as the line `AssemblyBuilder myAssembly = myAssembly.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAsmName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);` is invalid - `DefineDynamicAssembly()` is a static method so cannot be called on `myAssembly` (an instance). The code you are translating from populates one `object`-typed property with default-constructed instance, however your `CreateClass()` method can create types with properties of types that may not have a parameterless constructor, how do you intend for these to be initialized?